# Custom SUM Summary on XtraGridView

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I am using Devexpress 11.2

In a `XtraGridView` I want to show Summary `SUM` on a column with percent data
on the column i have repository spinEdit with mask "p2" 
so if I have the display value 50% the value is 0.5

if I have on grid values

```
0.5 - 50%  
0.3 - 30%   
0.2 - 20%
```

the Summary `SUM` will be 1 but i want to show 100%
can you help me please
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `DisplayFormat` property of the summary to capital "P".

See [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q206150.aspx) for reference.

Comment: yes , i didn't know the difference from "p" and "P"  thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom unbound column. 
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477

Then on [CustomUnboundColumnData](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic),

```
void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender,
DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "Percent" && e.IsGetData) {
        GridView view = (GridView)sender;
        DataRow row = view.GetDataRow(e.RowHandle); //If datasource = datatable
        //Use GetRow if custom business object and cast it.
        e.Value = Value*100 + "%"; //I am sure there is a better way.
    }
}
```

You can hide/remove the 'p2' column if you want.